# How to get all strings between XML tag

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to create a function that accepts a string as a parameter and returns a list of string between <>

Say for example a string that has these values:

```
string s = "<FirstName> John </FirstName> <LastName> Snow </LastName>";
```

I wanted to store each of that inside a list like so:

```
List<string> container = new List<string>();
container = getTypes(s);
foreach(string s in container){
Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

And the result would be:

```
Output:
FirstName
LastName
```

How do I do this?

Comment: use LinqToXML instead of a regex.

Comment: I'm not familiar with LinqToXML but the problem with what I've found so far is that, the functions tend to get the value between the XElement rather than the value between the <>

Comment: There’s a property that gives the elements name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string s = "<FirstName> John </FirstName> <LastName> Snow </LastName>";
var x = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Parse("<x>" + s + "</x>");    // needs single root element

foreach(var el in x.Elements())
    Debug.Print(el.Name.LocalName + " : " + el.Value);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!